# How do touch gestures work with WPF 4.5?

Tags: wpf, touch, gesture

I need to incorporate left and right flick gestures into an existing WPF Application. I have been searching for a long time, but I can't find any how-tos that apply to WPF 4.5. Plainly, how can I capture a flick to the left or to the right. Note that a finger-down plus, move to the left or right is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Never mind. I just found a question that you are going to close me for that doesn't actually answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104668/is-there-a-simple-way-to-handle-touch-events-like-flick-in-wpf4
I'll just figure it out myself. Somehow.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I had to use the Manipulation framework. It works well, but it is incredibly complex. You have to have a surface which to manipulate. If you use the Window itself you have to train your code to ignore some controls but not others. It was a nightmare.

Comment: Well that's encouraging! :\  thanks

Comment: I don't mean to be discouraging. The Manipulation API's work really well and make things really easy for what they are. I like working with it. When I first asked this question, I assumed that a flick or a swipe was a fairly simple form of manipulation. It is not because it is so high-level, and WPF doesn't support it directly.