# Anyway to add a new pen gesture to the ApplicationGesture pool of WPF?

Tags: c#, ios, wpf, gestures

I've scanned the net without success. Is there anyway to create a new pen gesture for WPF? (I do not have an android). More specifically, I would like to add a pen gesture that is a semicircle, concave up, to my Windows 7 application. (None currently exists that I can find). The curve will start and stop on the same horizontal line ( plus/minus 10 pixels), but be of varying radius of one to several characters.

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I recommand looking at those two links
1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104668/is-there-a-simple-way-to-handle-touch-events-like-flick-in-wpf4
2 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx

Comment: @KevinAvignon If I read it correctly, it still uses the built in gestures--not allowing me to make a new gesture? Thanks.