# Create a simple zoom for touch screen device

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming

I'm having a problem adding pinch zoom capabilities to a WPF C# application.

I already have a mouse wheel zoom that works very well and I would like to use it as a starting point.

Here is my code, as you can see, get cursor position and delta are not working.

```
private void pdfViewer_touchZoom(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    int idx = pdfViewer.CurrentIndex;

    //Get cursor position (this isn't working)
    var mousePoint = e.GetPosition(this.pdfViewer); 

    [...]

    //Delta not working (mouse wheel negative value)
    if (e.Delta < 0 && pdfViewer.Zoom > 0.4) /
            zoomMinus();
    else if 
       [...]

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? With touch devices you have to recognize *gestures*, see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-creating-your-first-touch-application) (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6105161/1997232)).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check this during the day and then, I'll answer you back.

Answer (score 0):

When I connect a *MouseWheel event handler* to a UIElement in .NET 5 WPF, it fires on the zoom gestures also: I get delta values of 120 for two-finger-widen (zoomin) and -120 for the two-finger narrow (zoomout)

In Xaml:

```
    <Image Name="ScoreImage" .. >
```

In code behind:

```
       // ..... initialisations
       ScoreImage.MouseWheel += this.RaiseMyMapMouseWheel;
    }


    private void RaiseMyMapMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta == 120 || e.Delta == -120)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Zoom event {e.Delta}");
        } else
        {  
            Debug.WriteLine($"Wheel event {e.Delta}");
        }
    }
```

The magnitude of wheel events can be anywhere between -2000 and +2000, so if you actually want to detect the 120's reliably, make sure you test a few in a row, before you draw the conclusion there is a zoom:

```
    private int countZoom = 0; 
    private void RaiseMyMapMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta == 120 || e.Delta == -120)
        {
            countZoom++;
            if (countZoom>2) 
              { 
                Debug.WriteLine($"Zoom event {e.Delta}"); 
                countZoom = 1; 
              }
        } else
        {   
            countZoom=0;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Wheel event {e.Delta}");
        }
    }
```